# Sql commands do not complete - hangs in console - hibernate

Tags: hibernate

What is wrong with this code? The SQL command does not complete, with show_sql, I am able to see the first sql command issued, and then it is left hanging out there indefinitely - the program does not proceed.

```
public class PersonDao {
private Configuration configuration;
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private Session session;

public PersonDao () {
    configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

}

public Person addPerson(Person p)
{
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try 
    {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Before person add");
        session.save(p);
        System.out.println("Person added");
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
    return p;
}

@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public boolean deletePerson(long personId) 
{
    boolean issuccessful = false;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Object persistentInstance = session.load(Person.class, personId);
        if (persistentInstance != null) {
            ((Person)persistentInstance).getResponses().clear();
            ((Person)persistentInstance).getOwnedEvents().clear();
            session.delete(persistentInstance);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        issuccessful = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        return issuccessful;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this happened because back in sqlplus, I was issuing some DML commands after which I did not issue a 'commit'. Therefore, the application hung up on issuing SQL statements in eclipse/hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
    configuration=new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```